# How to find an MSI file and launch installation from command line?

Tags: windows, cmd

**Goal:** I want to use CMD.EXE to find a single MSI, located in `C:\ProgramData` - not elsewhere - and then execute it.

**My attempt:** `dir /s /b C:\programdata\*"my program"*.msi | explorer`

**Problem:** Explorer opens but doesn't launch my MSI.

**Constraints:** I can't write a .BAT. So this must run on the command line.

Although that doesn't surprise me, I apparently don't understand CMD.EXE and piping well enough to do this. Any guidance?

Comment: This seems to work: FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('dir /s /b C:\programdata\*"my program"*.msi') DO set run=%i & "%i"   -- any improvements or comments?

Comment: the `set` statement seems unnecessary

Comment: `"C:\programdata\my program.msi"`  is all you need to type. Or to see success/failure - `"C:\programdata\my program.msi" && Echo Success || Echo Failure`

Comment: @bgalea - It appears that the OP does not know the exact location of the .msi file. Searching for any .msi file that matches a wildcard spec path seems not extremely responsible. It can be done, but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *.msi file is not an executable. It is a compiled installer script file which needs an interpreter for execution. The interpreter is `msiexec.exe`.

Searching for a file can be done with command **DIR** or with command **FOR**.

The better solution using command **FOR**:

```
for /R C:\ProgramData %# in ("my program*.msi") do %SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe /i "%#"
```

The more complicated solution using the commands **DIR** and **FOR**:

```
for /F "delims=" %# in ('dir /A-D /B /S "C:\ProgramData\my program*.msi" 2^>nul') do %SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe /i "%#"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `for /?`
- `msiexec /?`

Note: `%%#` instead of `%#` would be needed if one of the two command lines is used within a batch file.